# Closed-form for Floor Sum 3 - With knowledge of inner expression

Tags: summation, closed-form, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Consider the following sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left\lfloor\sqrt{k^2+N}\right\rfloor$$

Assume we know the factorization of $N$, in other words, we know for which $k$, $k^2+N$ will be square, according to [Fermat's Factorization Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method).

$N$ in this case is a positive odd integer.

Can we use this knowledge to get a closed-form for the sum?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

How large is $n$ compared to $N$? Is $n\approx\sqrt{N}$? You are counting the [lattice points in a region bounded by a hyperbola](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/dirichlet-hyperbola-method/), and $\sqrt{x^2+N}$ behaves like $x$ for large values of $x$. Additionally, it is not likely that your expression has a nice closed form, but it is for sure pretty close to
$$ \int_{0}^{n}\sqrt{x^2+N}\,dx = \frac{1}{4} \left(2 n \sqrt{n^2+N}-N \log N+2 N\log\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+N}\right)\right)$$
which if $n=\sqrt{N}$ behaves like $\left(\sqrt{2}+\log(1+\sqrt{2})\right)\frac{N}{2}\approx\frac{7}{6}N$ for large values of $N$.

Also notice that the problem of finding the first two terms of the asymptotic expansion of
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt{N}}\left\lfloor\sqrt{N\color{red}{-}k^2}\right\rfloor $$
as $N\to +\infty$ is exactly the [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem). In this case the first term of the asymptotic expansion is $\frac{\pi}{4}N$ for similar reasons.