# Calculate the sum with floor function.

Tags: real-analysis, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let $a$ be a positive number. Calculate the sum $$\sum_{1\le n\le x}\left\lfloor \sqrt{n^{2}+a} \right\rfloor$$

I tried to calculate first $\left\lfloor \sqrt{n^{2}+a} \right\rfloor-n$. But probably it won't help. 
Maybe you have some ideas how to solve it?

Comment: What is $x$ ....?

Comment: This looks related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2404418.